# Removing "www" from the domain directs to different site

Tags: html, web, dns

A novice here.  The support from mediaTemple and my current host have been quite unhelpful, so stackOverflow may be my hero.

My problem is that entering "www" before the domain and leaving it out direct to different servers.

The background on this is that I first registered the domain with mediaTemple and had a plan with their gridHosting, but after finding their service unsatisfactory, I cancelled my gridhosting plan and moved to another host.  This problem occurs even after updating the nameservers.  In short, the web server is hosted by proMinecraftHost, but the domain is registered under mediaTemple.

Support from both sides say it's due to dns and the nameservers needing 24-48 hours to update, but I'm fairly skeptical that it really is the cause.

Summarizing, [www.mscraft.org](http://www.mscraft.org) directs to the correct server, but [mscraft.org](http://mscraft.org)(mscraft.org) alone does not.

If anyone could help me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is question is likely off topic unless you're the one that's coding the changes in the configs to the servers for instance. If you're not then I suggest that this is better on super user - but will need to be cleaned up and made much more precise (what have you done, and what happened and what did you expect).

Comment: Can't find a problem - both addresses resolve to the same place. Listen to what the support people are telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you just have the old DNS info in your cache.  Try clearing your browser's cache, and also flushing your DNS.  On Windows you could do `ipconfig /flushdns` in a command prompt.  Also you could try pinging both addresses (with and without www).  You should see the same IP address for both, as I got `198.154.108.107` when I tried them.  In other words, I think it's working properly - you are just going to the old location because your machine is remembering too much.

Comment: Hmm, the strange thing is, I have tried that, except I used ifconfig (I'm on linux).
All my local machines have the problem,though I suppose it'll be fine if it is only confined to my machine.